# Double tap listener is not working in fragments

Tags: android, gesture

Double tap listener is not working in fragment. Firstly I wrote the and implemented on sample project that is working fine in sample project.In sample project there is only one activity.But when I am trying to integrate that sample code into my project it is not working fine.My real project has an activity that is loading a fragment on it.My requirement is when I double tap any where on that fragment(loaded on activity) i want some functionality against it.The problem is double tap is not working.Here is the code I am using to achieve it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // If user is not logged in
    if (new SessionHelper(this).getCurrentUser() <= 0)
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginScreen.class));
    else {
        mFragmentActivity = this;

        // Broadcast receiver initialized here
        mWifiStateReceiver = new WifiStateReceiver(mFragmentActivity);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
        initialize();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        setClickListerns();

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, this);

        gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(new GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                LogHelper.debugLog("single tap");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

                LogHelper.debugLog("doubletap");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Check if redirected via push notification
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("Notification", false))
            replaceFragemtn(new StatementOfAccount(), false);
        else
            replaceFragemtn(new HomeFragment(), false);

    }
}
```

I am implementing  **GestureDetector.OnGestureListener** in my Activity like this

```
public class FragmentActivity extends BaseClass
        implements View.OnClickListener, GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {}
```

and I am overriding **onTouchEvent()** method like this

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I am not able to figure this thing out what i am missing.Trying to solve this for a long time but no luck. Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use GestureDetector?
Сan you fit this option?

```
public static abstract class DoubleClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final long DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA = 300;

    private long lastClickTime = 0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        long clickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (clickTime - lastClickTime < DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA) {
            onDoubleClick(v);
        } else {
            onSingleClick(v);
        }
        lastClickTime = clickTime;
    }

    public abstract void onSingleClick(View v);

    public abstract void onDoubleClick(View v);
}
```

Comment: I want complete screen as double tap listener.Where should I implement?The frame layout that is loading fragment.Should I pass this on clicklistener?

Comment: Yes, you should write something like this: rootLayout.setOnClickListener(new DoubleClickListener(){....});

Comment: check that rootLayout is clickable = "true" and enabled = "true"

Comment: yes, I have set clickable true to the root layout still not working.